# TypeScript file is considered as xml when indenting

Tags: vim

**In a nutshell:**

In my `.vimrc` I have the following line to have vim indent xml files correctly:

```
autocmd FileType xml set equalprg=xmllint\ --format\ -
```

the weird thing is that now vim tries to use `xmllint` when I try to indent TypeScript files, and I don't understand why...

**More details**

When I open `test.ts` in vim, I can see that vim correctly detects the type (ie: `set filetype?` returns `filetype=typescript`).

But when I'm trying to indent this block of code

```
for(var i=0 ; i < 1 ; i++){
console.log(i);
}
```

by putting the cursor on a curly bracket and pressing `=%`, then this block is replaced with

```
Exception : System.Xml.XmlException: Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.
 at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e)
 [... eluded for brievity ...]
 at xmllint.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

(which means that vim launched the `xmllint` command and that this command failed (that failure is expected since it's not xml. But vim shouldn't have launched `xmllint` in the first place)).

Two other observations which might be useful are:

- when I remove this line from my `.vimrc` then indentation works as expected
- if I change the file extension to anything else (say `test.dummy`) then indentation works as expected

**Even more details**

- I'm using the TypeScript plugin https://github.com/leafgarland/typescript-vim . If I delete this plugin then `set filetype?` detects `.ts` files as `xml` (not sure where this matching comes from...)
- `:scriptnames` returns
  /etc/vimrc
  /usr/share/vim/vim81/defaults.vim
  /usr/share/vim/vim81/syntax/syntax.vim
  /usr/share/vim/vim81/syntax/synload.vim
  /usr/share/vim/vim81/syntax/syncolor.vim
  /usr/share/vim/vim81/filetype.vim
  ~/.vim/ftdetect/typescript.vim
  /usr/share/vim/vim81/ftplugin.vim
  /usr/share/vim/vim81/indent.vim
  ~/.vimrc
  /usr/share/vim/vim81/syntax/nosyntax.vim
  /usr/share/vim/vim81/plugin/getscriptPlugin.vim 
  /usr/share/vim/vim81/plugin/gzip.vim
  /usr/share/vim/vim81/plugin/logiPat.vim
  /usr/share/vim/vim81/plugin/manpager.vim
  /usr/share/vim/vim81/plugin/matchparen.vim
  /usr/share/vim/vim81/plugin/netrwPlugin.vim
  /usr/share/vim/vim81/plugin/rrhelper.vim
  /usr/share/vim/vim81/plugin/spellfile.vim
  /usr/share/vim/vim81/plugin/tarPlugin.vim
  /usr/share/vim/vim81/plugin/tohtml.vim
  /usr/share/vim/vim81/plugin/vimballPlugin.vim
  /usr/share/vim/vim81/plugin/zipPlugin.vim
  /usr/share/vim/vim81/ftplugin/xml.vim
  /usr/share/vim/vim81/indent/xml.vim
  /usr/share/vim/vim81/syntax/xml.vim
  /usr/share/vim/vim81/syntax/dtd.vim
  ~/.vim/ftplugin/typescript.vim
  ~/.vim/compiler/typescript.vim
  ~/.vim/indent/typescript.vim
  ~/.vim/syntax/typescript.vim
- Also, not sure it it's useful information, but I'm using ViM 8.1 on windows 10 (installed along with git-bash)

Comment: What's the output from `:scriptnames`? Also, which typescript plugin are you using? Vim doesn't have builtin typescript support.

Comment: I just added this information in the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure why your TypeScript is first detected as XML (maybe some other answer can dive into that), but it can happen that a generic (default, built-in) filetype is first detected, and then revised by a more specific detection (as in your case, via the TypeScript plugin). The problem you have is that the `'equalprg'` lingers one, because you used the shortcut `:autocmd` instead of a proper *filetype plugin*:

```
autocmd FileType xml set equalprg=xmllint\ --format\ -
```

If you only want to enable an option for certain filetypes, use `:setlocal option=value` (your use of `:set` would make the setting be inherited by new buffers opened from that one, which is wrong), and put the corresponding `:setlocal` commands into `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/{filetype}.vim`, where `{filetype}` is the actual filetype (e.g. `xml` here). (This requires that you have `:filetype plugin on`; use of the *after* directory allows you to override any default filetype settings done by `$VIMRUNTIME/ftplugin/{filetype}.vim`.) Proper plugins also undo any settings via the [`:help undo_ftplugin`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/usr_41.txt.html#undo_ftplugin) mechanism.

So, a proper configuration in your case would replace the `:autocmd` with `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/xml.vim`:

```
setlocal equalprg=xmllint\ --format\ -
let b:undo_ftplugin = (exists('b:undo_ftplugin') ? b:undo_ftplugin . '|' : '') . 'setlocal equalprg<'
```

With that, `'equalprg'` would still be briefly set as long as the filetype is XML, but it would then be undone by the command defined in `b:undo_ftplugin`, which Vim executes automatically when the filetype changes to `typescript`.